# Why the question I did answer with 2 vote ups deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Why the question I did answer (accepted answer) with 2 vote ups deleted? Related to the trajectory path. Isn't this against humanity? :D

Comment: You should try to spot that faulty user and _not_ answer his questions. This encourages him to keep on posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was deleted in conjunction with the suspension of an account engaged in serious misconduct throughout the site, misconduct that includes (among other things) abusing the good nature of our legitimate users.

Comment: ohh.. so in short.. I am in loss.. after all :(

Comment: Maybe; when I get to a real computer instead of my phone I'll untangle some of it.

Comment: I undeleted the question.

Comment: thanks bro.....